# error loading communication toolbox in scilab

Tags: scilab

Start Communication toolbox
Load macros
at line    32 of function        startModule ( C:\Program Files\scilab-6.1.0\contrib\comm_tbx_0.3_5.5_bin\etc\comm_tbx.start line 39 )
at line    82 of executed file   C:\Program Files\scilab-6.1.0\contrib\comm_tbx_0.3_5.5_bin\etc\comm_tbx.start
at line    10 of executed file   C:\Program Files\scilab-6.1.0\contrib\comm_tbx_0.3_5.5_bin\loader.sce
at line     1 of executed string

lib: Old binary lib detected. Please recompile it for Scilab 6.

Comment: Did you have any success since I updated the toolbox ?

Answer (score 0):

I have recompiled the toolbox for Scilab 6.1 and made it available on the Atoms portal. Just update the package list in the Atoms GUI (File/Update List of Packages), uninstall the old 0.3 version and install the 0.3.1 version.

S.